# PHP form validation with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajaxform

I'm trying to put my email form to work, but something is wrong.
I'm having no problems receving the email, but the process of ajax script with JSON (validation successful) isn't working properly and i don't know why.

My HTML:

```
 <form id="feedback" method="post" action="">

        <div class="enter-data"> 
          <label for="name"><span>Nome:</span></label>
          <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="formbox">
         </div>

       <div class="enter-data">                 
          <label for="email"><span>E-mail:</span> </label>
          <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="formbox">
         </div>

         <div class="enter-data">                
          <label for="telefone"><span>Telefone:</span></label>
          <input name="telefone" id="telefone" type="text" class="formbox">
         </div>

         <div class="enter-commnet">

           <label for="comments"></label>
           <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>

            </div>
             <div class="button_comment-bx">
    <button class="button_comment last"  name="send" id="send"  type="submit">Enviar</button>
               <button class="button_comment"  name="reset" id="reset" type="reset">Limpar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

My jquery **

> (EDITED)

**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#feedback").submit(function(){

        $(".error").remove();

        var check = true;
        var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;

        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var telefone = $("#telefone").val();

        // Validate Name
        if (name == '') {
            check = false;
            $('#name').after('<div class="error">* Preencha o seu nome!</div>');
        }
        else if (name.length < 3) {
            check = false;
            $('#name').after('<div class="error">* Nome demasiado curto!!</div>');
        }

        // Validate E-mail
        if (email == '') {
            check = false;
            $('#email').after('<div class="error">* Preencha o seu email!</div>');
        }
        else if (email.length < 5) {
            check = false;
            $('#email').after('<div class="error">* Email demasiado curto!</div>');
        }
        else if(!emailPattern.test(email)){
            check = false;
            $('#email').after('<div class="error">* E-mail não é válido!</div>');
        }

        // Validate Telefone
        if (telefone == '') {
            check = false;
            $('#telefone').after('<div class="error">* Preencha o seu telefone!</div>');
        }
        else if (telefone.length < 5) {
            check = false;
            $('#telefone').after('<div class="error">* Telefone não é válido!</div>');
        }


        // If validation is successful
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "contact3.php",
    data: $("#feedback").serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        $("#comments").after('<div class="success">Email enviado com sucesso!</div>');
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#telefone').val('');
        $('#comments').val('');
    } 
});  

    });
});
```

My PHP script for sending mail **

> (EDITED)

**

```
<?php


$to ='myemail@email.com';
// Contact subject
$subject ="Contacto Site"; 

$header="from: $name <$email>";

$nome = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$mensagem = $_POST['comments'];


// Corpo da mensagem
$body = "Nome: ".$nome;
$body.= "\n";
$body.= "Email: ".$email;
$body.= "\n";
$body.= "Telefone: ".$telefone;
$body.= "\n";
    $body.= "\n";
    $body.= nl2br($mensagem);



    // Enter your email address

    mail($to,$subject,$body,$header);

echo json_encode(array('mailSuccess' => 1));
```

help me please!

Comment: What's wrong ? Do you have errors, unexpected behavior ? Please explain more ;)

Comment: Shouldn't PHP return a sucess message after the email is sent and get jQuery to check for that message in the success function?

Comment: You didn't echo back the json array that contains the mailSuccess info, how is the ajax supposed to know if the ajax call is successful

Comment: "doesn't work" tells us nothing? Problem with the JS code? AJAX call not working? problem in the PHP? Email not working?

Comment: aarryy just said what I was trying to say.  In my form i echo TRUE or FALSE depending if the email sent successfully or not

Answer (score 2):

You are missing return value of your script. You have to echo json_encoded string, which jquery will check in `if (!response.mailSuccess)`

```
<?php
$to ='myemail@email.com'; // Contact subject $subject ="Contacto Site"; 

$header="from: $name <$email>";

$nome = $_POST['name']; $email = $_POST['email']; $telefone = $_POST['telefone']; $mensagem = $_POST['comments'];


// Corpo da mensagem $body = "Nome: ".$nome; $body.= "\n"; $body.= "Email: ".$email; $body.= "\n"; $body.= "Telefone: ".$telefone; $body.= "\n"; $body.= "\n"; $body.= nl2br($mensagem);



// Enter your email address

mail($to,$subject,$body,$header);

echo json_encode(array('mailSuccess' => 1));
?>
```

**EDITED:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "contact3.php",
    data: $("#feedback").serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        $("#comments").after('<div class="success">Email enviado com sucesso!</div>');
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#telefone').val('');
        $('#comments').val('');
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but the problem continues, i think that is the problem the echo json_encoded string, which jquery will check in if (!response.mailSuccess). How i said im receving the emails from the form without any problem, but the script don't trigger the last part of json validation

Comment: Thanks a lot again for you effort ;), but now when i submit the page refresh and turns blank... my question was edited with you advices. thanks

Comment: I will try it again. pls wait